# Nested XML data AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We have some data in this format:

```
<doc>
  <event timestamp="20200529032100">
    <row attr="test" id="3">data</row>
    <row attr="gfds" id="6">data</row>
    <row attr="sadf" id="8">data</row>
  </event>
</doc>
```

We want to extract the data in each row, but the timestamp at the same time. We are trying to do this with an AWS ETL job and CSV as output.

We tried to add a classifier for `row`, but then we don't get the timestamp. When we try to add a classifier for `event`, we get the timestamp, but after the etl job, the fields extracted from row only shows up for events with only one `row`-entry inside it. For the ones with multiple `row`-entries, there is only one row in the resulting CSV, and the fields we try to extract from `row` are empty, instead of getting the same number of csv rows, as there are `row` entries, which is what we want.

Is this possible to solve with AWS Glue, or is this something we have to create on our own?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation and weren't able to build a table using just a custom classifier. We wrote a job that read the XML into a dataframe using the schema that we specified, then used the explode method to pivot nested elements into their own rows.

Note that you'll need to add the spark_xml jar as a dependent jar for your job (or dev endpoint if you're developing in a notebook) as described in https://towardsdatascience.com/use-aws-glue-and-or-databricks-spark-xml-to-process-xml-data-21eaef390fda.

Rough outline of what you should try in your job:

1. Define a schema for the structure of the element that represents the rows you will read into the data frame initially. In your example, if you want one row per event, define a schema for your event element that includes the row element as an array type. Something like:

```
    mySchema = StructType(
        [StructField('_timestamp',LongType(),True),
         StructField('row', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_VALUE', StringType(), True),
                                      StructField('_attr', StringType(), True),
                                      StructField('_id', LongType(), True)]), True), True)])
```

2. Read the XML file into a dataframe using the schema

```
    spark_df = spark.read.format("xml").options(rowTag="event").options(nullValue="").schema(mySchema).load("s3://bucket/path/to/xml")
```

3. Use explode to create a new dataframe with one row per row tag

```
    row_df = spark_df.withColumn('eachrow', explode(col('row')))
```

This will give you a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
|    _timestamp|                 row|      eachrow|
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
|20200529032100|[[data,test,3], [...|[data,test,3]|
|20200529032100|[[data,test,3], [...|[data,gfds,6]|
|20200529032100|[[data,test,3], [...|[data,sadf,8]|
+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

4. Select the timestamp attribute and row attribute/values.

```
final_df = row_df.select(col('_timestamp').alias('timestamp'), col('eachrow._VALUE').alias('row_value')...)
```

You can then write out the dataframe in whatever format you need.